# Sum BigDecimal values in List with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a simple class:

```
class Simple {
    private String count;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private String label;
}
```

and have a List: `List<Simple> simples = new ArrayList<>();`
how I can sum all amounts of all simples in list with Lambda in Java 8?

Comment: are you talking about the stream API ?

Comment: yes! can I add all amounts with stream api?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is quite easy with a Stream and a reducer :

```
BigDecimal sum = simples
    .stream()
    .map(Simple::getAmount)
    .reduce(BigDecimal::add)
    .get();
```

Comment: You may use `.orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO)` instead of `.get()` to get a useful result for empty lists. Or use `.reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)` in the first place, so you don’t have to deal with an `Optional` at all…

Comment: My code giving error at BigDecimal::add saying "cannot resolve method add"
Any help ?

Comment: You will notice this error on reduce when the mapped value is not of type BigDecimal, if the mapped value was of type double you can do .map(p -> BigDecimal.valueOf(p))

Comment: this code is not working when getAmount() method return null

Comment: @Arnaud Denoyelle, so let me see if I understood, from the stream you apply a map function to get the amount, from amount you made a reduce to group the values using add()? And what is the use for the get() in the final ? I didn't understand for what is the get

Comment: @lipesmile Without it, you get an `Optional<BigDecimal>`. The `get` just converts it to a `BigDecimal`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Thanks for the explanation

Comment: flawless answer arnaud!

Comment: In order to prevent null values, you might want to add Object::nonNull function as a predicate. `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
BigInteger sum = simples.stream()
                        .map(Simple::getAmount)
                        .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add);
```

Comment: once getAmount is null : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.math.BigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.java:1291)